# How to use stack area High chart using Dynamic values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts, stacked-area-chart

This is my code where I fetch data

```
var compdata = new Array();
compdata = '<?php echo $compdata; ?>'; 
compdata = JSON.parse(compdata);
var dlen    = compdata.length;
var cmname  = new Array();
var cmdate  = new Array();
var crank   = [];
var mktshare = new Array();
i=0;
for(var key in compdata ){
    cmname[i]  = compdata[key].MFG_NAME;
    cmdate[i]  =  months.name(new Date(compdata[key].CAL_WID).getMonth())+'-'+new Date(compdata[key].CAL_WID).getFullYear(); 
    mktshare[i]  = parseFloat(compdata[key].MKT_SHARE);
i++;
}
alert(cmname); alert(cmdate); alert(mktshare);
```

In the alerts I am getting the values as below:

```
nova, apc, msd, rbc // for cmname
mar-2013, apr-2013, aug-2013, oct-2013 // for cmdate
1,2,5,7 // for mktshare
```

I need to display these values and show it in the graph `http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked`.

Here is the js-fiidle link http://jsfiddle.net/k3kuepch/

The x-axis must be the `cmdate`, y-axis must be the `mktshare` and in place of countries that is Asia, Africa, Europe, etc I must show the `cmname` i.e `nova, apc, msd, rbc` in my case.

The problem is that I am unable to understand where to give x-axis, Y-axis and the `cmname` values according to the output that I am getting which I mentioned in the beginning of my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe better is prepare correct structure in JSON like array of series with points / names instead of using your parser.